# For loop is working only once

Tags: for-loop, attributes, save, magento-1.9

For the below code, where I am trying to update a custom attribute called branding. The for loop is running only for one iteration and stopping. It is updating only the first product in the list and not looping any further.

Can anyone kindly let me know why this is happening?

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

// require magento core
require_once 'app/Mage.php';

// execute on admin store
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

foreach($products as $product){
     echo $product->getSku();
     $product->setData('branding', 'kib');
     $product->save();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving total product just save attribute for product by using **saveAttribute**

```
// require magento core
require_once 'app/Mage.php';

// execute on admin store
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
echo $products->getSelect();//this will give sql query just run your db.
foreach($products as $product)
{
    $product->setBranding('kib');
    $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'branding');
}
```

One more solution without loops

```
$store_id = 0;
$product_ids = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()        
        ->getAllIds();//you can apply some filters also

  Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
      $product_ids,//array of ids
      array('branding' => 'kib'),//you can add some other attributes also as key value pair
      $store_id
  );
```